# Create sites in runtime with different domains

Tags: python, django, django-settings, url-pattern

I would like to create django sites in runtime, using the same settings.py

For example, I have in my django_site table the following rows,

```
1 | 127.0.0.1:8001 | sitea
2 | 127.0.0.1:8002 | siteb
3 | 127.0.0.1:8003 | sitec
```

My django goes to my settings.py, fetchs the site_id and brings the right site.. What I would like to do is:

```
1 | 127.0.0.1:8001 | genericsite
```

but then the user access:

```
127.0.0.1:8001/sitea -> it brings sitea
127.0.0.1:8001/siteb -> it brings siteb
```

How would you go about setting up your urlpatterns? For instance, if I go to my admin page again, create a `sited`, I should be able to access `sited`. P.s. All the info I need after that will be filtered based on the site the user is requesting..

I really need a hand with this! Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at [django-subdomains](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains).

While it manages different sites as sitea.127.0.0.1:8001, siteb.127.0.0.1:8001 etc unlike you want but you really can check their `SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware` to inspirate yourself. And may be subdomains is just what you want :)

It also contains helpful template tags, adds subdomains to request variable and many other goodies.